# PHP: How can I replace specific data?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little script so when I get my data output from my Mysql table and the data I receive is -1 then it should display Expired if it is anything other than -1 it should just display the data.

This is what I currently have. I have tried some stuff but my PHP and MySQL is 0.

```
$sql = "SELECT ban_id, timestamp, perp_steamid, perp_name, admin_steamid, admin_name, bantime, timeleft, reason FROM nomercyg_CTBan_Log";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["ban_id"]. "</td><td>". date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $row["timestamp"]). "</td><td>". $row["perp_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["admin_name"]."</td><td>". $row["bantime"]." min". "</td><td>". $row["timeleft"]." min"."</td><td>". $row["reason"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You need to add a WHERE clause.

Comment: What do you mean by data? Which field are you talking about? Do you mean the field `ban_id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you can just add an `if` statement inside your `while` loop to decide if you should display 'Expired' or the data you caught itself.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if($row['band_id] == -1) {
    echo '<tr><td>Expired</td></tr>; //Or add as many columns as you need here
  } else {
    echo "<tr><td>". $row["ban_id"]. "</td><td>". date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $row["timestamp"]). "</td><td>". $row["perp_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["admin_name"]."</td><td>". $row["bantime"]." min". "</td><td>". $row["timeleft"]." min"."</td><td>". $row["reason"]. "</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this way but i think its not the best solution

```
$sql = "SELECT ban_id, timestamp, perp_steamid, perp_name, admin_steamid, admin_name, bantime, timeleft, reason FROM nomercyg_CTBan_Log";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo . . . . . . . .. .. . ... . ;

        echo "<tr><td>";

            if ($row["ban_id"] <=0){
                $row["ban_id"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["ban_id"];
            }else {
                echo $row["ban_id"];
            }
        echo "</td><td>";
            if(date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $row["timestamp"]) <=0){
                $row["ban_id"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $row["timestamp"]);
            }else {
                echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $row["timestamp"]);
            }
        echo "</td><td>";
            if ($row["perp_name"]<=0){
                $row["perp_name"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["perp_name"];
            }else{
                echo $row["perp_name"];
            }
        echo "</td><td>";
            if ($row["admin_name"]<=0){
                $row["admin_name"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["admin_name"];
            }else{
                echo $row["admin_name"];
            }
        echo "</td><td>";
            if ($row["bantime"]<=0){
                $row["bantime"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["bantime"];
            }else{
                echo $row["bantime"];
            }
        echo " min";
        echo "</td><td>";
            if ($row["timeleft"] <=0){
                 $row["timeleft"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["timeleft"];
            }else{
                echo $row["timeleft"];
            }
        echo " min";
        echo "</td><td>";
            if ($row["reason"]<=0){
                 $row["reason"] = 'EXPIRED!!!';
                echo $row["reason"];
            }else{
                echo $row["reason"];
            }
        echo "</td></tr>";


    }
echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```